# Texture does not wrap where expected

Tags: opengl

I am generating a bitmap (1 byte per pixel) and attempting to use it for alpha blending.  I am successfully using the bitmap, but it appears that the texture does not wrap lines as I expect.

When I use the following code, it wraps where I would expect, given the input image.  I get the set of Xs that I expect.

```
std::ofstream file{ R"(FileName.txt)" };

file << "width: " << gs.width() << "\theight: " << gs.height() << "\n";

for (int i = 0; i < gs.height(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gs.width(); ++j)
    {
        file << ((gs.alpha()[j + i * gs.width()]) ? 'X' : ' ');
    }
    file << "\n";
}
```

When I load the texture it appears that the width of the texture does not match `gs.width()`, since it wraps oddly.

[image: Output when expecting a lower case 'a'.]

This is the code that I use to create the texture and load it with the bitmap.

```
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, gs.width(), gs.height(), 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gs.alpha());
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: To be clear, is the texture supposed to be slanted like that? It looks an awful lot to me like the result of reading/writing a bitmap image with improper alignment; they require each scanline to begin on a 4-byte boundary. For a 1-byte image like you are suggesting, this means if the number of pixels per-row is not a multiple of 4 you need to do some padding to satisfy alignment.

Comment: And why are you using a depth texture for an alpha mask? `GL_RED` is much more sensible, there is actually a single-channel internal format that can be represented using only 8-bits (`GL_R8`) if you use a color format; the smallest internal format for a depth texture is 16-bit per component.

Comment: The alignment was the problem.  I ended up changing the (un)pack alignment to 1 and everything worked.

Comment: @Graznarak please put ut then as answer.maybe useful for others.

Comment: @MichaelIV How do I flag a comment as an answer?

Comment: You can't,write it down in the answer panel.